# Comparing arrays and changing and array elements name Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compared two arrays and change the element name that is not in `notAssigneed` to `unassiged`

So far I have a forEach looping throu

```js
let original_assigned = []

oemCat.forEach(element => {
  if (element.t_count === '1') {
    //console.log(element)
    original_assigned.push(element.oem_type_category)
    //console.log(element.label + ' '+element.t_count)
  }
})

let original_assigned = ['GM', 'Other']
let current = [['Other', 1667.0],['GZ', 185.0]]
```

I need to be able to replace the element in current that is not in original assigned with `unassigned` strings.  Any thoughts?

Final desired would be

```
['Other', 1667.0]['unassigned',185.00]
```

example of oemCat

```
{id: "19", 
dealer_id: "869", 
comp_id: null, 
oem_type_category: "Other", 
label: "Other", 
oem_cat_variable: "Other"
oem_type_category: "Other"
summit_id: null
t_count: "1"}
```

Comment: what do `notAssigneed ` and `oemCat` look like?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the name.   NotAssigned is original_assigned.   oemCat is just a array of objects.  I have the logic that grabs the ones that I need.  Right now I am just trying to compare the two and change whichever doest not exist to unassigned.

Comment: it could be better if you provide one example element of `oemCat`

Comment: @hgb123 Ok, I added an example of a oemCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map` and `includes`

```js
let original_assigned = ['GM', 'Other']
let current = [['Other', 1667.0], ['GZ', 185.0]]

const res = current.map(([key, value]) => [
  original_assigned.includes(key) ? key : 'unassigned',
  value
])

console.log(res)
```

---

#### References

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: nice way to keep 'current' as it originally was. From OP's "replace the element in current that is not in original assigned with unassigned " I got that they wanted a change in current and not a new array

Answer (score 0):

```
current.forEach(el => {
  if (!original_assigned.includes(el[0])){
    // your unassigned go here
    el[0] = "unassigned";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my code with a final desired.